# One to one relation in EntityFramework code first - Set Columnames of relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i created the below entitie.

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [...]
    [Key]
    public String ID { get; set; }
    [Column("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

}
```

with:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(a => a.CreatedBy)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal();
}
```

When the tables are created the columname of CreatedBy is "User_ID" although I used the Column attribute. The Columname should be "CreatedBy".

I changed the above code line to

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(a => a.CreatedBy)
       .WithRequiredPrincipal().Map(e =>   e.MapKey("CreatedBy"))
```

and added in the pakage manager a new migration with add-migration. On Update-Database I get the message: Entities in 'DALDbContext.Users' participate in the 'User_CreatedBy' relationship. 0 related 'User_CreatedBy_Source' were found. 1 'User_CreatedBy_Source' is expected.

My tables are empty. Does someone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what would have lead to your exact issue. However, I would probably just stick to either attribute based configuration or fluent api based configuration. In both cases its best practice to include both the navigation property and foreign key. Moving to this approach is nice and clean and may sort your problem.

**Attribute based**

```
public class User
{
   [Key]
   public string Id { get; set; }

   [Column("CreatedBy")]
   public int? CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
   public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent api based**

```
public class User
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public int? CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
   public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // add in configuration for table name, pk, etc
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
      .Property(p => p.CreatedByUserId)
      .HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
      .HasOptional(x => x.CreatedBy)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedByUserId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked for me. I added later one propertie more with also the same relation named ParentUser. This time the based attribute solution didn't worked. I got the Exception "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types". I added "modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.ParentUserId)      .HasColumnName("ParentUser");
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(x => x.ParentUser)    .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentUserId);"
So this time I had to mix up the attribute and fluent api based solution.